# Getting the entity manager

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

i'm using `spring data jpa` but i want execute some costume query so how can i get the `entity manager` in my java classes to make `entityManager.createQuery(..)`

```
   <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceYous" />
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="persistence" />
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />

   </bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain your EntityManager as in any other spring application:

```
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {
    private EntityManager em;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public Collection loadProductsByCategory(String category) {
        em. .... 
        ....
    }
}
```

See: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight

Comment: Thanks I try `@Autowired` instead of `@PersistenceContext` and it works .. they are the same ?

Comment: `@PersistenceContext`is the JPA standard annotation for injecting an `EntityManager`. `@Autowired` is Spring-specific, but allows to inject any bean, not just `EntityManager`s.

Answer (score 2):

In your applicationContext.xml, check that you have the following:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

That will add support for several annotations, such as `@PersistenceContext`, that injects an `EntityManager`. So in your Spring-managed beans, you can do:

```
public class MyClass {
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.entityManager = em
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery(...);
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you want to add suport for *just* `@PersistenceContext`, and not the other annotations that `<context:annotation-config />` supports, you would delete that from the `applicationContext.xml` and add the specific [BeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" scope="singleton">
   <!-- Optional configuration of PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor, for advanced use cases -->
</bean>
```

Comment: i didn't put `<context:annotation-config />` and it works do you have a explanation ?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly follow this link to get the steps required to implement..
[check this link](http://examples.lishman.com/spring/data-jpa/custom-repository-methods.html)

In second step he uses `@Autowired private JdbcOperations operations;`
But that doesn't work for me, so i used the following code.. Which worked for me.

```
@Component
public class MayorRepositoryImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements MayorRepositoryCustom {

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getUsers(String role) {
        return getJdbcTemplate().query("Write your custom query",new RowMapper<Employee>(){
            @Override 
            public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rownumber) throws SQLException {   
                // Mapping each row and adding to list and returning the list 
                Employee employeeBean=new Employee();  
                employeeBean.setId(rs.getInt("id"));  
                employeeBean.setEmployeeNumber(rs.getString("employeeNumber"));
                employeeBean.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                employeeBean.setWorkEmailAddress(rs.getString("workEmailAddress"));
                employeeBean.setPersonalEmailAddress(rs.getString("personalEmailAddress"));
                return employeeBean;  
            }  
        });
    }
```

}
This is perfectly working for me..
If you find any difficulty let me know to help you.

Cheers

Comment: man my question it's very simple i want get `entityManager` why you talk about `JdbcDaoSupport ` and all these complex stuff !!!

Comment: @Aminoo yOU need entityManager for executing custom query.. This is another way to achieve your requirement. whether you are using entityManager or JdbcDaoSupport doesn't matter right..